# How to make this for loop more efficient?

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop

I have written code for a function that finds all the connected vertices from a triangulated surface.
The surface is made from a vertex list (VL) *m x 3* and a face list (FL) *n x 3*. Each row of the VL is one point (x y z).
Each row of the FL indexes three rows of the VL. These three points build one triangle.

```
function List = findVLInd(FL, StartingPoint)

  List = StartingPoint;

  for a = 1:50000
    List = [List;find(List(a,1)==FL(:,1))];
    List = [List;find(List(a,1)==FL(:,2))];
    List = [List;find(List(a,1)==FL(:,3))];

    Lz = FL(List,:);
    List = [List;Lz(:,1);Lz(:,2);Lz(:,3)];
    List = unique(List);
  end 
end
```

After the script runs there are 50,000 numbers that can be used as indexes to the VL.

Unfortunately, this is really slow. Probably because of the for loop and the list that grows each loop. The number 50,000 is arbitrarily set. My FL has approximately 116,000 rows, but not all are connected to each other.

How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: What does `List(a,1)` do inside the loop? Given how you extend `List`, element `a` is rather arbitrary. The list can grow faster or slower than `a`, and `unique` will change the order of the elements. Other than that, the way to speed this up is to use a proper index to more quickly find the neighboring faces. Build a list of vertices that links to each face used by each vertex.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I thought by chance, a will always index some different point. I will try to bild a list like you recommended

Comment: if you provide some sample data and few lines of explanation that would be useful. My gut feeling is that you should avoid the for loop completely. Also crude equivalence is not robust. Something in the line of bsxfun applying abs(x-y) and finding the min seems to make the job. If you provide some specific data I can try it out. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Syntax-wise I'd suggest the following:

```
function List = findVLInd(FL, StartingPoint)

  List = StartingPoint;

  for a = 1:50000
    List(end+1, :) = [find(List(a,1)==FL(:,1))];
                      find(List(a,1)==FL(:,2))];
                      find(List(a,1)==FL(:,3))];

    Lz = FL(List,:);
    List(end+1:end+size(Lz,1), :) = [Lz(:,1);Lz(:,2);Lz(:,3)];
    List = unique(List);
  end 
end
```

This removes the reassignment operation `List = [List; X]` which copies the content of list into another variable then deletes it (though the new variable has the same name as the previous one) and replaces it with an appending operation, which is much faster in Matlab, though still slow. By calling the first three lines in your `for` loop in a single block, I can also reduce the number of such operations.

As per the comments by [ChrisLuengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) and [pacta-sunt-servanda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3684758/pacta-sunt-servanda), there are other issues you might want to address that aim at improving the functionality of your code.